# Triggering a Kubernetes-based application from AppEngine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently looking into triggering some 3D rendering from an AppEngine-based service.

The idea is that input data is submitted by an API client to this **web service**, which then invokes an internal Kubernetes GPU enabled application ("**rendering backend**") to do the hard work.

1. GPU-enabled clusters are relatively expensive ($$$), so I really want the cluster to be up and running on demand. I am trying to achieve that by setting the autoscaling minimum to 0 for the rendering backend.
2. The only pretty way of "triggering" a rendering task on such a cluster I could think of is via Pub/Sub Push. Basically, I need something like Cloud Tasks, but those seem to be aimed at long running tasks executed in AppEngine, not Kubernetes. Plus I like the way Pub/Sub decouples the web service from the rendering backend.
3. Google's Pub/Sub only allows pushing via HTTPS and only to a validated domain. It appears that Google is forcing me to completely "expose" my internal rendering backend by assigning a domain name to it, which feels ridiculous. I cannot just tell Pub/Sub to invoke `http://loadbalancer.IP.address/handle_push`.

This is making me doubt my architecture.

How would you go about building something like this on GCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the GKE perspective:

You can have a cluster with a dedicated GPU-based nodepool and schedule your pods there using [Taints and tolerations](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-taints). Additionally, you can control the number of nodes in your nodepool using [Autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler) so that, you can use them only when your pods are to be scheduled/run.

Consider that this requires an additional *default-non-GPU-based nodepool*, where system pods are being run.

For triggering, as long as your default pool is running, you'd be able to deploy your application and the autoscaling should start automatically. For deploying *from* an App Engine application, you might want to consider talking to the Kubernetes API directly [through a library](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/).

Finally and considering the nature of your current goal (3D rendering), it might be best to use [Kubernetes Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/job). With these, you can complete an sporadic computational load, allowing the nodepool to downsize once is finished.

Wrapping up, you can have a minimum cluster with a zero-sized GPU-based nodepool that will autoscale when a tainted job is requested to be run there, and once the workload is finished, it should automatically downscale. These actions can be triggered from GAE, using one of the client libraries.